# How to pass an angular expression variable to ng-focus? ng-focus="setFocus({{var}}"

Tags: html, angularjs

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="formGroup in formGroups  |  filter: {page: PAGE_current}">

<td>
    <input type="text" id={{formGroup.key}} name={{formGroup.name}}
           ng-focus="setFocus('{{formGroup.name}}')"
           minlength={{formGroup.min}} maxlength={{formGroup.max}}
           size={{formGroup.size}}/>
</td>
</tr>
```

setFocus is called, but the return value is: No help for selected field: {{formGroup.name}}:undefined

Console Element:

```
<input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName"
       ng-focus="setFocus('lastName')"
       minlength="2" maxlength="20" size="50/">
```

Comment: Should have been more clear - I'm in side an ng-repeat so it has to be dynamic.  Sorry about that.

Comment: You should show the `ng-repeat` directive in your example. The problem can probably be solved by using the `$index` special variable created by the `ng-repeat` directive.

Comment: Thanks george, question edited.  I'll close when it lets me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td class="editInput">
   <input type="text" id="{{formGroup.name}}" name={{formGroup.name}}
          ng-focus="setFocus([formGroup.name])"
          required minlength={{formGroup.min}} maxlength={{formGroup.max}}
          size={{formGroup.size}}
          ng-model="editUser[formGroup.name]"/>
</td>
```

This post answered my question 52624566, sorry newbie on angular.

Answer (score 0):

No need of using {{ }} i.e. string interpolation with event binding.
When passing a value as parameter to a function directly use getter and the control name without interpolation. This gives the FormControl then use .value to get the current value of the control.

Eg : `setFocus(formGroup.get('name').value))`